# .Net Visual Studio default controllers have errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I apologise in advance for displaying small images(I don't know how to enlarge them) and displaying lots of code but most of them are just for reference and give readers a brief picture of what I'm doing.

I'm very new to .Net and using Visual Studio. I'm trying to implement a database called Inventory. It has a many to many relationship!(Category to Products). Currently I have created the pages for it(Images below). I used Visual Studio's default controllers for the CRUD methods but now they have errors which I can't fix. I've labeled all the errors in CategoryController.cs.

Note: I can upload the project if someone is kind enough to look through it since it's easier this way.

Here is the Index page for Category
[image]

When I click on Details for Drink it will list all the Products that have that categoryId.(Drinks = 1)

[image]

Error List (Right-Click -> Open image in a new tab)
[image]

```
public class Category {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    }
public class Product{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int CategoryId{get;set;}
    public String Brand {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Price{get;set;
}
```

Models/Category.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Inventory.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Controllers/CategoryController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Inventory.DAL;
using Inventory.Models;

namespace Inventory.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext();

        // GET: Category
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Categories.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Category/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);  <--Line 31 Error 3 and 4
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Category/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Categories.Add(category);
                db.SaveChanges();      <-- Line 55 Error 5
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);<--Line 69 Error 6 and 7
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Category/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified; <--Line 86 Error 8
                db.SaveChanges(); <--Line 87 Error 9
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id); <--Line 100 Error 10 and 11
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Category/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id); <--Line 113 Error 12 and 13
            db.Categories.Remove(category);
            db.SaveChanges(); <--Line 115 Error 14 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose(); <--Line 123 Error 15
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

DAL/InventoryContext.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Inventory.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace Inventory.DAL
{
    public class InventoryContext
    {
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public InventoryContext()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>
            {
            new Product{Id=1,CategoryId=1,Brand="Coca Cola", Name="Coca Cola",Barcode="00001",Price=150},
            new Product{Id=2,CategoryId=1,Brand="Pepsi", Name="Pepsi",Barcode="00011",Price=150},
            new Product{Id=3,CategoryId=2,Brand="Homebrand", Name="Baked Beans",Barcode="0002",Price=250},
            new Product{Id=4,CategoryId=2,Brand="Homebrand", Name="Baked Patatos",Barcode="0022",Price=250}

            };
            Categories = new List<Category>
            {
            new Category{ID=1, Name="Drink", Products = Products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == 1).ToList() },
            new Category{ID=2,Name="Canned Food", Products = Products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == 2).ToList() }

            };
            foreach (var product in Products)
                product.Categories = Categories.Where(c => c.ID == product.CategoryId).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: db.Categories.Find(id) id is int? and Find method expects Category parameter,

Comment: But to be able to search of the id it has to be an int

Comment: Use db.Categories.Find(new Category(){ Id = id})

Comment: I did it and it says Inventory.Models.Category does not contain a defintion of Id

Comment: i think is ID intead of Id

Comment: Category category = db.Categories.Find(new Category() { ID = id });.                             


List<Category> InventoryContext.Categories! The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.GenericList<Inventory.Models.Category> Find(System.Predicate<Inventory.Models.Category>) has some invalid arguments

Comment: db.Categories.Find(category => category.ID == id)

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'inventory.Models.Category'

Comment: db.Categories.Find(c => c.ID == id)

Comment: I've fixed it already! thanks for your input

Comment: what about the errors remain?